# Login SOAP Web Service

Tags: php

Segue meu codigo de login ao webservice soap

```
   if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "login") {
$soapClient = new SoapClient(WEST_SOAP_WSDL,
    array("trace" => WEST_SOAP_TRACE, "login" => WEST_SOAP_LOGIN, "password" => WEST_SOAP_PASS));

try {
    $clienteId = $soapClient->loginAuth($_POST["username"]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
     print_r($e);
}

if ($clienteId) {
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);

    $_SESSION["auth"]["id"] = $clienteId;
    $_SESSION["auth"]["username"] = $_POST["username"]; 

    try {
        $_SESSION['cliente'] =   serialize($soapClient->getClientDataById($clienteId));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
     print_r($e);
    }
```

Como eu poderia Restringir o Acesso ao meu Painel do assinante em php nos status abaixo ? :

```
        inativo
        cancelado
        serasa
```

Comment: você gostaria de restringir quando os status fossem estes?

Comment: sim, exato isso mesmo

Comment: seu status é definido pelo SOAPConnection.call()? por exemplo: 200 => ok; 500=> error server; 305 => inativo?

Comment: nao ,  desta forma :  select name="status" id="status" style="width: auto;" disabled="disabled">
          <option value="S">
            ativo</option> 
          <option value="N">
            inativo</option>

Comment: então é setado no banco de dados, correto?

Comment: correto, no banco de dados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi da sua questão, você necessitaria de uma cosulta ao banco de dados com o usuário passado pela **session**, assim verificando se este **usuário** primeiramente encontra-se cadastrado, e logo em seguida se o o mesmo tem o **status** diferente dos 3 listados por exemplo:

```
 $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
 $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";

 $status "SELECT status FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";

  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $active = $row['active'];

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($count == 1){
     if($status != 'inativo' && $status != 'cancelado' && $status != 'serasa')
     {
        header("location: welcome.php");
     }
     else
      {
        echo"erro";
      }
  }
  else {
    echo"erro";
  }
```

Eu adicionei o **select** do status em uma variável para servir de verificação, assim avalia se está ou não atendendo o mesmo.